# Why are some light bulbs labeled “Not For Sale in the United States"?

Tags: light-bulb

My wife was in a convenience store in New York City, looking for light bulbs. She came across several packages of 40 watt GE bulbs. The packages were labeled in English, and said, in part, “Not For Sale in the United States”. Putting aside the fact that New York City is in the United States (although there were also packages of bulbs labeled in Spanish), why would light bulbs be labeled that way?

The only additional information she has is that they were manufactured in Hungary.

Comment: United States(North America) uses 120 volts.  A lot of the rest of the world uses 240 volts.  They might also been made for free giveaways from companies(sometimes marked not for sale).  Spanish might mean for Spain.

Comment: Can you get us any more details about said bulbs?

Comment: @crip659 — it’s pretty common in New York City for local stores to have products labeled in Spanish, Chinese, Korean, Japanese, Hebrew, etc. depending on the ethnicity of the neighborhood.

Comment: Those bulbs may have been packaged before Trump in 2019 rolled back the 2007 regulation that made most incandescents illegal.

Comment: Assuming they are 120V or thereabouts bulbs with bases generally used in the USA, could be goods sold wholesale to distributor outside USA at lower price than to distributor in USA, and marked that way to protect USA market (like pharma).  Could be design or manufacturing defect not to USA standards sold in country where the standards are "different" or where manufacturer is more willing to risk law suits.  Could be the bulb has some quirk that is  trademark or patent protected in USA but not elsewhere.

Comment: @Pete Becker  Probably is, Canada has to have products with French and English on packaging.  Are labels on packages or are labels placed on packages(tape on)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel — see my edit. Manufactured in Hungary. Nothing more.

Comment: @r13 I'm guessing your native language isn't English - you have one unusual quirk. "Shall" is usually considered an instruction or command, while "should" is a suggestion. I've noted that you seem to use "shall" a lot, but I doubt you're really giving a _command_, but are, instead, offering a _suggestion_. You may want to consider switching that up in your vocabulary, as "shall" comes across rather demanding and authoritative, as opposed to a simple helpful suggestion. (Don't worry, your English is _far_ better than my `<any other language>`, and this is the only quirk I've noticed.)

Comment: @r13 -- I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that those bulbs were produced during the U.S. incandescent ban (2007-2019). I'd look for LED bulbs instead, for both cost and environmental reasons.

> In 2014, the Department of Energy issued regulations that would extend the efficiency standards of the 2007 EISA law to some specialty bulbs, effective January 2020.[91] The new standards would apply to Edison, globe, and candelabra bulbs among others. In February 2019, the Department of Energy announced a proposal to withdraw this change. In September 2019 the Trump administration rolled-back these energy efficiency standards for lightbulbs with the Energy Department's publication of regulations in the Federal Register.[92][93] The Energy Department announced the reversal of the 2014 regulation that would have taken effect on January 1, 2020 and implemented the last round of energy-saving light bulb regulations outlined by the Energy Independence and Security Act of 2007.[94]
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-out_of_incandescent_light_bulbs#United_States

Comment: IMHO, let capitalism do the job - which matches in this case with removal of the regulations. For 99% of people, saving (a) 90% of the energy cost over the lifetime of the bulb combined with (b) bulbs that (even the cheap junk LEDs) last many times as long as incandescent bulbs, means that even if the incandescent bulb costs 50 cents and the LED costs $5.00, the LED clearly wins on $. And $ is what most people care about. That leaves the incandescents for people who value the color/look/etc. so much or who have an old EZ-Bake oven to give to the grandchildren.

Comment: Nope. Impulse buyers don't factor in long-term cost. Most people don't think more than five minutes ahead (look at all the cheap, disposable bicycles we buy our kids for example). We'd be burning energy through tungsten filaments like mad for decades. We'd also be burning anything that makes our cars run cheap if not for regulation, no matter the pollution cost. Humans are not clever animals, on the whole.

Comment: I disagree. It has taken a **long** time to convince users, but in the end, education can work just fine. Take an "EnegyStar" approach - government mandating labelling of estimated total energy usage on major appliances - that gets the point across without saying "thou shalt only buy the efficient stuff". Plus most (I hope...but I do know not "all") people can be trained easily to think of lifetime cost for a light bulb - you know you will use it until it wears out. That is different from bicycles (or clothes or musical instruments) for kids - many people get the cheap stuff because...

Comment: Energy Star doesn't work because it informs people. It works because it _enforces_ certain standards. As much as I'd like to give people credit, hard evidence proves otherwise. At any rate, this isn't the place for a debate.

Comment: (a) they don't know if the kid will ever make full use of the item (decide they are bored with cycling, don't like the style of the clothing or don't have the talent/persistence for the instrument) and/or (b) will break/tear/destroy the item (due to typical kid carelessness or other reasons).

Comment: Nah. If people could be trained to purchase wisely we'd have learned how a century ago. People buy cheap crap because it's cheap. End of story.

Comment: I know. Just felt I had to put in my 0.02  until a moderator deletes. But it does get to the heart of the issue.